# How to add a modify search function to a results page

Tags: php, mysql, search, html-select

I have a PHP page which displays the results of a users database query for a classified ad's site. The user initiates a search on the homepage and selects the parameters of the search using select  boxes and then the form is submitted.

Once on the results page I need to allow the user to modify the search parameters using select boxes down the side of the page (the same ones on the homepage). How do I go about making the option selected in each select box match what was selected on the first page. i.e. if the user selects make: Audi and Model: A8 I want the drop down for make and model to list all the other options, but have the Make preselected to Audi and the Model pre-selected to A8.

I know about using option selected for option boxes in a select statement, but how can I take a select statement that has already been coded for the results page and insert a selected variable for the option that should be selected first.

I hope that makes sense. I haven't posted any code because I'm in search of ideas rather than help fixing a code problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits the search form, all the variables posted in the form is available to you via $_POST or $_GET. Use these variables to re-select the correct information in the search form on the results page.

```
<select name="model">
   <option value="a8" <?php echo (isset($_POST['model']) && $_POST['model'] == 'a8') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>A8</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

The dynamic database way:

```
<select name="model">
<?php
$getRows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM models");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRows))
{
    echo '<option value="" ' . ((isset($_GET['model']) && $_GET['model'] == $row['model']) ? 'selected' : '') . '></option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Now you only need one if statement. You should btw **use GET parameters**, so that the user has the opportunity to bookmark the results for later use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What impact will this have on the page load time running if statements for each option? There are about 12 select boxes in total, with around 20 options for each.

Comment: Looping these short lists will not affect the load time for the client user, but your code will be quite ugly with all those if statements

Comment: In your case I would consider fetching the lists from a database, which would help simplify your code considerable. I've edited my answer to show you an example.

Comment: I considered storing the details of the options in an array with a single IF statement rather than storing it in a database. Would you reccomend that,or stick with storing it in a DB?

Comment: Well, the reason why I think you should stick with the DB model is because it's easier to maintain the options. Often new options come along or is no longer relevant. That might not be the case right now, but it certainly will when your project grows.